# MinGW changes the HOME environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, mingw

I'm using MinGW and I'm trying to set an environment variable called **HOME**.

I set the variable to "**C:\Users\jdoe**" but when I run printenv from the command prompt it tells me the value of HOME is "**/c/Users/jdoe**".

I've test out other variables names, and this change doesn't happen.  Only for **HOME**.  When I remove the **HOME** environment variable printenv no longer lists **HOME**.

Some simple programs like mkdir and rm don't mind this change but gcc is having none of it.  I'd like to be able to build this project on both windows and linux.  Having a working **HOME** variable would be very useful.  Why is this happening and where can I make it stop?

Answer (score 5):

By "run printenv from the command prompt" you mean running it from the MSYS prompt?

If this is the case, the change of the HOME environment variable can be justified because MSYS tries to give you a GNU/Linux-like environment, where there aren't drive letters. There is only one filesystem, the /, and everything else is mounted into this.

Hence, in MSYS C:\ becomes /c/, etc...

The /c/Users/jdoe in MSYS is the same directory as C:\Users\jdoe in cmd.exe, or in the explorer.